# Flatten transparency of derivative colors

Tags: color, transparency, symbols

I'm creating an illustration in **Ai CS3** heavily using symbols. I need to create derivative symbols, out of other symbols, with lighter colors. The transparency tool is for color seek, but as soon as I get the right color saturation, I need to have the colors (including gradient stops) recalculated, as the objects have to be opaque. For example `100% black * 0.4 transparency` has to become `40% black with 1.0 transparency`.

I tried Flatten Transparency, but the product gets over-complicated (the shapes are lost, Ai creates additional groups and clipping paths).

**So, what would be the easiest way to flatten the transparency the way I want?**

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly, but does http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9311/5489 speak to your problem at all? If not, then disregard :)

Comment: Thanks Brendan. In general - yes it's quite similar, except that it'd be really hard to manually sample gradient stops. I'm starting to think of a script to do the whole process.

Comment: Can you use the Blend -> Blend Options? And are you needing to have exact steps of calculations? I can only understand so much of this question though. Sorry if you could elaborate a bit more, maybe it would help.